# Getting one or more error occured exception in downloading via HttpClient and Parsing with XElement

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, rss

I am creating a news app that need to support news of multiple language in visual studio with xamarin c#. I am using the code below.

```
List<FeedItem> feedItemsList = new List<FeedItem>();
                try
                {
                    HttpClient wc = new HttpClient();

                    var html = wc.GetStringAsync(new Uri(url)).Result;


                    XElement xmlitems = XElement.Parse(html);
                    // We need to create a list of the elements
                    List<XElement> elements = xmlitems.Descendants("item").ToList();

                    // Now we're putting the informations that we got in our ListBox in the XAML code
                    // we have to use a foreach statment to be able to read all the elements 
                    // Description  , Link , Title are the attributes in the RSSItem class that I've already added
                    List<FeedItem> aux = new List<FeedItem>();
                    foreach (XElement rssItem in elements)
                    {
                        FeedItem rss = new FeedItem();

                        rss.Description = rssItem.Element("description").Value;
                        rss.Link = rssItem.Element("link").Value;
                        rss.Title = rssItem.Element("title").Value;
                        feedItemsList.Add(rss);

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
```

This code is not working for https://news.google.com/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=zh-Hans&hl=china&q=topstories&output=rss

But works for http://news.google.com/?output=rss

**Additional Information:**
This code above works fine for any feedurl in windows phone app.

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*? Do you get exception? If yes, where is the exception? unexpected result?

Comment: I have written the exception in question title itself that **one or more error occured**

Comment: Which line does the exception occur on?  Is it the download that fails, or the parse?   Have you checked to see if there is an InnerException set with more detail?

Comment: Come on `one or more error occurred` doesn't mean anything. what is the details of inner exception.

Comment: @EZI I think this may be because of unsupported unicode characters in the rss feed.